# jdl studio Error while parsing applications and entities

Tags: jhipster

I'm getting an error while parsing applications and entities.

```
Error: The name 'clientc' is a reserved keyword and can not be used as an entity field name.
ERROR! ERROR! Error while parsing applications and entities from the 
JDL Error: The name 'clientc' is a reserved keyword and can not be used as an entity field name.
```

Here is my code

```
entity Fournisseur {
    nom String required,
    adresse String required,
    numCompte String required,
    numTel String required
}

entity Cat {
    nom String required,
}

entity Article {
    nom String required,
    designation String required,
    tva Float required,
    prixUnitaireHT Float required,
    prixTTC Float required,
    cat Cat required
}

entity Stock {
    quantite Integer required
    article Article required
}

entity Clientt {   
    nom String required,
    adresse String required,
    numCompte String required,
    numTel String required,
    numCin String required,
}

entity Commande {
    date LocalDate required,
    clientt Clientt  required
}

entity LigneCommande {
    quantite Integer required,
    commande Commande  required,
    article Article required
}

entity LigneArticle {
    qte Integer required,
    fournisseur Fournisseur required
}

entity Facture {
    date Instant required,
    totalFinale Float required,
    modeReglement Float required,
    dateReglement Instant required,
    commande Commande required
}
```

Comment: What JHipster version are you using?  Also please read the docs and see how to properly format relations between entities, for example `Stock` is expecting `article` to be an `enum` instead of an entity.  https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#relationshipdeclaration https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#enumerationdeclaration

Comment: Using JHipster version 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the version you are using (v5.0.2), the error messages for JDL have been improved.  In the latest version, the error message is correct with `Error: The type 'Cat' is an unknown field type for field 'cat' of entity 'Article'.`

You need to use relationships rather than attempting to embed the entities in each other.  Remove the related entities from within the `entity` sections and use something similar to below:

```
relationship OneToOne {
    Stock{article required} to Article{stock}
    Article{cat required} to Cat{article}
    Clientt{commande required} to Commande{clientt}
    LigneCommande{commande required} to Commande{ligneCommande}
    LigneCommande{article required} to Article{ligneCommande}
    LigneArticle{fournisseur required} to Fournisseur{ligneArticle}
    Facture{commande required} to Commande{facture}
}
```